# WPF DataTemplate - define in which grid's column TextBox will be displayed

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox DataTemplate

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label />
            <TextBox />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And grid defined as

```
<Grid Margin="10 10 10 10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myObservableCollection}"  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myItemTemplateSelector}" />
</Grid>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to force this textbox to appear in particular grid's column - with no luck so far.

I tried

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

but it doesn't work.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
        <Label />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

doesn't work either.

"2" is only for testing, ultimately I would like to use binding there.

Is it possible to do this with DataTemplate (to define in which grid's column I want TextBox to appear)?

---

I want to end up with TextBoxes placed like this.

[image]

So TextBox's position on grid should depend on value from template.

Modifying ItemsControl to appear in particular grid's column

```
<Grid Margin="10 10 10 10">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding myObservableCollection}"  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myItemTemplateSelector}" />
</Grid>
```

is giving me this

[image]

which is not what I'm expecting. I want TextBoxes to be put in different columns, based on values from their templates.

Comment: At the moment whole `ItemsControl`, with all items, takes **one cell** of your `Grid`. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @erem Setting `Grid.Column` only effective if the element is direct child of a `Grid`

Comment: You can data bind to the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` Attached Properties as you can see in the [Bind Grid.Row / Grid.Column inside a DataTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432847/bind-grid-row-grid-column-inside-a-datatemplate) question, but as @har07 correctly mentioned, it will only work if the element is in a `Grid`.