# Use ItemsControl for Grid Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, itemscontrol

```
<Grid Name="WeightGrid" Grid.RowSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{Binding WeigntGridMargin}" MouseDown="WeigntGridWrap_OnMouseDown" MouseMove="WeigntGridWrap_OnMouseMove" MouseUp="WeigntGridWrap_OnMouseUp">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            ...
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="weightTT"/>
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="75">
          <StackPanel.Background>
                   <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Size.WPF;component/Assets/ruller-bg.png" />
          </StackPanel.Background>
          <TextBlock Margin="0, 42, 0, 0" Foreground="#c0b6d1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18">0</TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="75">
              <StackPanel.Background>
                          <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Size.WPF;component/Assets/ruller-bg.png" />
              </StackPanel.Background>
              <TextBlock Margin="0, 42, 0, 0" Foreground="#c0b6d1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18">1</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="75">
               <StackPanel.Background>
                          <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Size.WPF;component/Assets/ruller-bg.png" />
               </StackPanel.Background>
               <TextBlock Margin="0, 42, 0, 0" Foreground="#c0b6d1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18">2</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
         ...
</Grid>
```

I have Grid with many columns. Every column is `StackPanel` with different column number and with different number in `TextBlock`. To decrease amount of code I want to use ItemsContol or something like this to build grid columns. But one problem - How can I bind ColumnNumber to ItemsControl Item? Possibly there is solution [Bind Grid.Row / Grid.Column inside a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432847/bind-grid-row-grid-column-inside-a-datatemplate) But another problem - How can set amount of Columns?

---

UPD :

```
<ItemsControl Name="WeightItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid Name="WeightGrid"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="{Binding WeigntGridMargin}" MouseDown="WeigntGridWrap_OnMouseDown" MouseMove="WeigntGridWrap_OnMouseMove" MouseUp="WeigntGridWrap_OnMouseUp">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GridColumn}" />
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

This is what I have now. But I still don't know how to set Amount of columns that should be created to it `ItemsControl` (Currently it's just binded to some collection `Cells` but it should be just number as amount of columns).

Answer (score -1):

```
 <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                                <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Completion}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

you can modify the code as you want..or if you don't use the binding you can simply do like this

```
<ItemsControl>
                        <system:String>ItemsControl Item #1</system:String>
                        <system:String>ItemsControl Item #2</system:String>
                        <system:String>ItemsControl Item #3</system:String>
                        <system:String>ItemsControl Item #4</system:String>
                        <system:String>ItemsControl Item #5</system:String>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Manual adding `<system:String>ItemsControl Item #1</system:String>` or similar is what I've tried to avoid.